# Library for programming Abstract Syntax Trees in Python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm creating a tree to represent a simple language. I'm very familiar with Abstract Syntax Trees, and have worked on frameworks for building and using them in C++. Is there a standard python library for specifying or manipulating arbitrary ASTs? Failing that, is there a tree library which is useful for the same purpose?

Note, I am not manipulating *Python ASTs*, so I think the AST module isn't suitable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASTs are very simple to implement in Python. For example, for my [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) project (a complete C parser in Python) I've implemented ASTs based on ideas borrowed from Python's modules. The various AST nodes are specified in a YAML configuration file, and I generate Python code for these nodes in Python itself.

Comment: Quite nice. I had hoped for something already nicely abstracted into a library, with documentation, etc (no offence). My grammar has only 6 types, so its relatively straightforward to write it out myself. I just thought there might be a standard library people use.

Comment: @Paul, if you give it some thought, the best way to use an AST is to define a class for each node type. This is the most polymorphic and clean way to traverse the tree later (with a NodeVisitor). Therefore, you have to write those classes anyway. Considering how little code an AST in Python requires, I doubt that a library is needed here

Comment: @AndersonGreen: thanks, refreshed the main link and removed others

Answer (score 1):

[`pyast`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyast/1.0) is a package for building declarative abstract syntax trees.

Answer (score 0):

If you represent your grammar elements as expressions in pyparsing, you can attach a parse action to each expression which returns a class instance containing the parsed tokens in a parser-specific type. There are a couple of examples on the pyparsing wiki that illustrate this technique ([invRegex.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/invRegex.py), [simpleBool.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py) and [evalArith.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/eval_arith.py)).  (These grammars all use the operatorPrecedence built-in, which can obscure some of the grammar structure, but

Answer (score 0):

This blog entry, though short on implementation detail, describes a nice interface that Python ASTs could implement.

http://chris-lamb.co.uk/2006/12/08/visitor-pattern-in-python/

Comment: This article provides a good actual implementation of the pattern: https://tavianator.com/the-visitor-pattern-in-python/.